# Cycle Through Excel Worksheets and Pausing Each One

Tags: excel, loops, wait, worksheet

I am trying to do something which should be relatively simple but I just cant get it working correctly, I keep killing Excel.

I have a workbook with several sheets containing data, pivots and charts. I want to cycle between a select number of sheets, which I have managed to do, code below, but what I am trying to achieve now is to get it to pause for say 10 seconds on each sheet before moving to the next sheet.

```
Sub LoopThroughFlaggedSheets()

Dim StartIndex, EndIndex, LoopIndex, CountIndex As Integer

StartIndex = Sheets("Dashboard").Index
EndIndex = Sheets("Sales By Policy Type").Index
CountIndex = 5

For CountIndex = 1 To CountIndex
    For LoopIndex = StartIndex To EndIndex
        MsgBox Sheets(LoopIndex).Name

    Next LoopIndex
Next CountIndex
End Sub
```

So at present it loops 5 times through the worksheets between Dashboard and Sales By Policy Type, the messagebox is just for me so I know what its doing. I just need it to pause for whatever specified time period between each sheet. I know something needs to go within the LoopIndex loop but I cannot for the life of me figure out where and which command.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

EDIT Try this:

```
Sub LoopThroughFlaggedSheets()

Dim StartIndex, EndIndex, LoopIndex, CountIndex As Integer

StartIndex = Sheets("Dashboard").Index
EndIndex = Sheets("Sales By Policy Type").Index
'CountIndex = 5

'For CountIndex = 1 To CountIndex
    For LoopIndex = StartIndex To EndIndex
        'MsgBox Sheets(LoopIndex).Name

        Debug.Print Now()
        Debug.Print Sheets(LoopIndex).Name

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

        Debug.Print Now()

    Next LoopIndex
'Next CountIndex

End Sub
```

I have taken out your outer `CountIndex` loop to stop the `Wait` running 25 times. I have reduced the wait time to 1 second to show the principle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I put that within my LoopIndex loop and it kills excel without moving through the worksheets

Comment: I have edited the answer to show the code as part of your sub. I have a feeling that your two loops are putting a massive wait into the process in the order of 250 seconds without showing any indication that something's happening. I've taken out the outer loop, shortened the `Timevalue` and put some `Debug.Print` lines in to show progress.